# Как программно проиграть рингтон из raw папки?

Tags: java, android

Я делаю пользовательский DialogPreference, который выводит окно выбора рингтона. Кроме списка доступных в системе рингтонов, в окне выводятся дополнительные .mp3 файлы приложения, находящиеся в папке raw. В обработчике нажатия я проигрываю выбранную мелодию. Установленные рингтоны проигрываются без проблем, а вместо моих raw файлов проигрывается мелодия по умолчанию.

Проигрывание mp3 файлов:

```
try{
   int resId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_my_mp3", "raw", 
   mContext.getPackageName());
   Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/"+resId);
   Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, uri);
   ringtone.play();
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ошибок не вызывает, идентификатор находит, но играет дефолтную мелодию. Может подскажете, где копать?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена заменой Ringtone на MediaPlayer.

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
//конструктор
public ExtraRingtonePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
}
//проигрывание при нажатии на строчку списка с мелодией
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if ( mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
            }

            int resId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_pressed_sound", "raw", mContext.getPackageName());
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + resId);

            if (uri != null) {
                if (uri.toString().length() > 0) {
                    try
                    {

                        mPlayer.reset();//очистить от предыдущей мелодии, иначе выдаст ошибку ввода/вывода
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, uri);
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RingtoneManager` если не может найти файл подсовывает стандартный рингтон, попробуйте в таком формате

```
android.resource://com.example.package/raw/name_of_my_mp3
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как я только не перепробовала этот путь